# Column Indexing in Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Has anyone tried to create column indexes while writing to parquet? Parquet 2.0 provided support for Column Indexes in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1201 but I'm not able to figure out how to use that.
Basically while writing to parquet from spark, I want one column to be indexed, such that when I read it again, I can have faster queries. But I am not able to figure out how to proceed with this.

Comment: Support for column index at read will be implemented in spark 3.2 (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26345). However, I don't see any work about support of column index at write. So I don't think it is possible to create column indexes within Spark as of today (September 2021)

Answer (score 1):

The column index is write to parquet file while using parquet-mr library v1.11+ automatically. So spark just need implement read function, and it has been implemented in spark v3.2.0.